# Erro de conversão ao tentar popular uma variável

Tags: c#

Tenho isso:

```
model.Items = new List<CatalogItemResponse>() { qryMode };
```

dá erro porque qryMode é do tipo **CatalogItemResponse** e não uma lista do tipo de **CatalogItemResponse**

Como inputo qryMode para dentro de model?

Comment: Eu percebi que os "downvotes" QUASE SEMPRE são para Posts de produtos Microsoft (VB, C#, etc...) ... estranho, né?

Comment: Dei um AddRange(qryMode) e vou testar

Comment: Aparentemente seu código está correto, fiz até um código de teste no dotnetFiddle e funcionou corretamente: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8dX2IX

Comment: eu já vi casos de perguntas com +30 up no SOen, aqui a pergunta parecida com -3. Sobre a pergunta, model.Items já está instanciada? Se sim, só dar um add(qryMode).

Comment: Não funfou, mas vi algumas coisas estranhas. Vou debugar e posto, mas como eu atribuo o objeto em uma list?

Comment: Não há nada de errado com o seu código. Validei isso localmente com código de teste e funciona na perfeição. Existe aí algo mais!

Comment: Acho que faltou isso: `model.Items = new List<CatalogItemResponse>()` e depois `model.Items.AddRange(qryMode)`

Comment: Vou remover os comments de desabafo, pois estão fora do escopo do site, mas fiquei chateado mesmo. E depois removo esse também

Comment: Oque faltou na pergunta foi especificar que qryMode era um lista. Por isso com AddRange funcionou. Sem essa informação seria difícil alguém ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Se `model.Items` for do tipo `List<CatalogItemResponse>`, tente isto:

```
model.Items = new List<CatalogItemResponse>();
model.Items.Add(qryMode);
```